# How to position and design triangle after text correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a small triangle on the top-right corner after a text. My code looks like:

```css
.amenity_note{
    margin-right:10px;
}
.amenity_note:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #6eabff transparent transparent;
     /* top: 0px; */
    position: absolute;
}
.category_note:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #6eabff transparent transparent;
     /* top: 0px; */
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="category_note">Category Name</span>
      <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="amenity_note">First Name</span>
      <strong>$10</strong>
      <strong>[25]</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="amenity_note">Last Name</span>
      <strong>$10</strong>
      <strong>[25]</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

I have successfully placed the triangle to the top-right corner, however, I want it to make two following changes:

1. Place that triangle to little lower positions, so that it aligns with the text
2. Make triangle unfilled for the category as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/xxVjoWe

Comment: @Simplicius Yes

Comment: @Simplicius It's working on codepen. But, I don't know why the cared is missing on my project. Should I include any other assets?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem to require much complexity. I did it with a simple trick:

```css
.amenity_note {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.amenity_note:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent #6eabff transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.category_note {
  position: relative;
}

.category_note:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent #6eabff transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: 5px;
}

.category_note:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 0;
  border-color: transparent #ffffff transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: -14px;
  top: 6px;
  transform: scale(.7);
  transform-origin: top right;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="category_note">Category Name</span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="amenity_note">First Name</span>
          <strong>$10</strong>
          <strong>[25]</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="amenity_note">Last Name</span>
          <strong>$10</strong>
          <strong>[25]</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: @SarojShrestha, I'd use this, it's probably the best solution currently, using the `border` trick instead of `clip-path`, as shown here.

Comment: It's working for amenity, however, for category one line is missing https://ibb.co/YTGPVPg

Comment: Never, mind I got the idea, I just need to decrease the width for that white triangle.

Comment: @SarojShrestha I made some changes to my previous answer that seem to be better

Answer (score 2):

Using borders to generate a triangle has some flaws, I used `clip-path` in this example, but you'd probably be better when using SVGs.

```css
:root {
  --carretCategoryBgc: #fff;
  --carretAmenityBgc: #6eabff;
  --carretSize: 10px;
  --carretCategoryBorder: 1px;
}

.category_note,
.amenity_note {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 14px;
}
.category_note::before, .category_note::after,
.amenity_note::before,
.amenity_note::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.category_note::before,
.amenity_note::before {
  z-index: -50;
}
.category_note::after,
.amenity_note::after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}

.category_note::before {
  top: var(--carretCategoryBorder);
  right: var(--carretCategoryBorder);
  height: calc(var(--carretSize) - (var(--carretCategoryBorder) * 2));
  width: calc(var(--carretSize) - (var(--carretCategoryBorder) * 2));
  background-color: var(--carretCategoryBgc);
}
.category_note::after {
  height: calc(var(--carretSize) + 1px);
  width: calc(var(--carretSize) + 1px);
  background-color: var(--carretAmenityBgc);
}

.amenity_note::before {
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  height: var(--carretSize);
  width: var(--carretSize);
  background-color: var(--carretAmenityBgc);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="category_note">Category Name</span>
      <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="amenity_note">First Name</span>
      <strong>$10</strong>
      <strong>[25]</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="amenity_note">Last Name</span>
      <strong>$10</strong>
      <strong>[25]</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's working on codepen. But, I don't know why the cared is missing on my project. Should I include any other assets?

Comment: @SarojShrestha There are none required. But `clip-path` is still considered an *experimental* property, although all modern browsers support it. You may accidentaly copyed the SCSS version instead of the CSS of the Codepen, try to use the one of this post.

Comment: I am using the chrome browser. No, I have tried with compiled CSS as well as the above-given CSS.

Comment: @SarojShrestha. Weird, opening the Codepen in Chrome works for me.

Comment: I have checked on the other browser as well, it's not showing on any of them. Could it be because of conflict with any other library? If that could be how could I start debugging cause, there is nothing on the console.

Comment: @SarojShrestha, No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there as goes allowing the two to follow the changes. You should use `group selectors`
Also, I noticed you didn't have `position: relative;` So I added that for both classes.

Now you can move the position using top, left, right, bottom.

I used top in this cause.

```
.category_note,
.amenity_note {
  position: relative;
}

.amenity_note:after,
.category_note:after {
  top: 7px;
}
```

And as goes for the filled and not filled.? Did you consider using fontawesome to add these icons? it makes things easier.

I'm using [Bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage) since it's free.
Also you should use this website to encode the SVG and use it in your CSS
[SVG encodr](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) you should take the SVG code from the Bootstrap Icon and place it in the website and copy the ready for CSS code. Now the icon is `background-image`

```css
.category_note,
.amenity_note {
  position: relative;
}

.amenity_note:after,
.category_note:after {
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.amenity_note {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.amenity_note:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='1em' height='1em' viewBox='0 0 16 16' class='bi bi-caret-up' fill='%236eabff' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M3.204 11L8 5.519 12.796 11H3.204zm-.753-.659l4.796-5.48a1 1 0 0 1 1.506 0l4.796 5.48c.566.647.106 1.659-.753 1.659H3.204a1 1 0 0 1-.753-1.659z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  position: absolute;
}

.category_note:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='1em' height='1em' viewBox='0 0 16 16' class='bi bi-caret-up-fill' fill='%236eabff' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M7.247 4.86l-4.796 5.481c-.566.647-.106 1.659.753 1.659h9.592a1 1 0 0 0 .753-1.659l-4.796-5.48a1 1 0 0 0-1.506 0z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="category_note">Category Name</span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="amenity_note">First Name</span>
          <strong>$10</strong>
          <strong>[25]</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="amenity_note">Last Name</span>
          <strong>$10</strong>
          <strong>[25]</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Note that you may want to change the color as anyone would want. In order to do that once you open the SVG file, you will have to find `fill="currentColor"` and now what you have to do is to replace the " currentColor" with the color you want.

The second step is to open the SVG encoder and post the new SVG so the `color` you choose to get encoded and be ready to be used in CSS.

you can also use other SVG or fontawesome icons. if you want.

Comment: could you share the jsfiddle link. As per your suggestion, the triangle turns into a random polygon. I am open to using SVG as well.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please let me know if this way was helpful.

Comment: Could you make that #6eabff

Comment: I made an edit to show you how to change the color. Feel free to copy the snippet it has the color you want.